# Why is i18next-http-middleware defaulting back to fallback language

Tags: express, i18next, express-handlebars, next-i18next

I am setting up i18next middleware in my express handlebars app, i18next works for any translation I put as the fallbackLng, the problem is none of the i18next middleware features are working like for example getting the lng param from url

Here is my i18next init setup

```
import { filterNodesByGroups, getNodeLabel } from "@ory/integrations/ui"
import express, { Request, Response } from "express"
import handlebars from "express-handlebars"
import * as fs from "fs"
import * as https from "https"

import { middleware as middlewareLogger } from "./pkg/logger"
import { toUiNodePartial } from "./pkg/ui"
import {
  register404Route,
  register500Route,
  registerErrorRoute,
  registerHealthRoute,
  registerLoginRoute,
  registerRecoveryRoute,
  registerRegistrationRoute,
  registerSettingsRoute,
  registerStaticRoutes,
  registerVerificationRoute,
  registerWelcomeRoute,
} from "./routes"

const i18next = require('i18next')
const i18nextMiddleware = require('i18next-http-middleware')
const Backend = require('i18next-fs-backend')
const HandlebarsI18n = require("handlebars-i18n");

const app = express()

console.log("were here")
i18next
  .use(Backend)
  // .use(languageDetector)
  .use(i18nextMiddleware.LanguageDetector)
  .init({
    debug: true,
    backend: {
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-path-concat
      loadPath: __dirname + '/i18n/{{lng}}/{{ns}}.json'
    },
    fallbackLng: 'en',
    preload: ['en', 'fr'],
    // nonExplicitSupportedLngs: true,
    // supportedLngs: ['en', 'fr'],
    load: 'languageOnly'
  })

app.use(middlewareLogger)
app.set("view engine", "hbs")
app.use(i18nextMiddleware.handle(i18next))

HandlebarsI18n.init();

app.engine(
  "hbs",
  handlebars({
    extname: "hbs",
    layoutsDir: `${__dirname}/../views/layouts/`,
    partialsDir: `${__dirname}/../views/partials/`,
    defaultLayout: "main",
    helpers: {
      ...require("handlebars-helpers")(),
      jsonPretty: (context: any) => JSON.stringify(context, null, 2),
      onlyNodes: filterNodesByGroups,
      toUiNodePartial,
      getNodeLabel: getNodeLabel,
    },
  }),
)

registerStaticRoutes(app)
registerHealthRoute(app)
registerLoginRoute(app)
registerRecoveryRoute(app)
registerRegistrationRoute(app)
registerSettingsRoute(app)
registerVerificationRoute(app)
registerWelcomeRoute(app)
registerErrorRoute(app)

app.get("/", (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  res.redirect("welcome", 303)
})

register404Route(app)
register500Route(app)

const port = Number(process.env.PORT) || 3000

let listener = (proto: "http" | "https") => () => {
  console.log(`Listening on ${proto}://0.0.0.0:${port}`)
}

if (process.env.TLS_CERT_PATH?.length && process.env.TLS_KEY_PATH?.length) {
  const options = {
    cert: fs.readFileSync(process.env.TLS_CERT_PATH),
    key: fs.readFileSync(process.env.TLS_KEY_PATH),
  }

  https.createServer(options, app).listen(port, listener("https"))
} else {
  app.listen(port, listener("http"))
}
```

Here is the new package [example](https://github.com/i18next/i18next-http-middleware/blob/master/example/basic/index.js#L55)

The deprecated package has an example that is close to the new package [here](https://github.com/i18next/i18next-express-middleware/blob/master/examples/basic-handlebars/index.js)

What could be wrong with my initialization of i18next-http-middleware?

Edit: If I change the language in the url header from en to fr in the debug output I get several language changes between requests for example:

```
i18next: languageChanged en
i18next: languageChanged fr
{"level":"info","message":"HTTP GET ... "}
i18next: languageChanged en
i18next: languageChanged en-US
{"level":"info","message":"HTTP GET ... "}
i18next: languageChanged en
i18next: languageChanged en-US
{"level":"info","message":"HTTP GET ... "}
i18next: languageChanged en
i18next: languageChanged en-US
i18next: languageChanged en
i18next: languageChanged en-US
i18next: languageChanged en
i18next: languageChanged en-US
i18next: languageChanged en
i18next: languageChanged en-US
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is a problem of integration between https://github.com/Aller-Couleur/handlebars-i18n/ and https://github.com/i18next/i18next-http-middleware

i18next-http-middleware sets the language on a clone of `i18next` instance that is reported on request (`req.i18n`), while handlebars-i18n use the i18next global instance, and I don't see anyway it can be changed.

I opened an issue on handlebars-i18n: https://github.com/Aller-Couleur/handlebars-i18n/issues/43 as it could be an easy fix on their side.

Comment: Also see my commit to fix it in the repository, by adding a middleware https://github.com/openfoodfacts/kratos-selfservice-ui-node/commit/901a3f675c10dd47c449686ac5e8fa7e1541a4f1

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the middleware is not applied.
Try to move this line after the `app.set("view engine", "hbs")` line:

```
app.use(i18nextMiddleware.handle(i18next))
```

Comment: The middleware is applied I edited my comment to include the debug output. I am getting a language change but it re changes back to the fallback.

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example in a github repo...

Comment: I wrote up a readme on how to develop under OpenFoodFacts i18n development I made it as minimal as possible https://github.com/openfoodfacts/kratos-selfservice-ui-node/tree/i18n. Thank you

Comment: sorry, but this is not minimal… just i18next, express and handlebars… the rest is too much… sorry

Comment: btw: where are you using these translation keys? https://github.com/openfoodfacts/kratos-selfservice-ui-node/blob/i18n/src/i18n/en/translation.json#L4

Comment: There should be something like calling the t function in your views: https://github.com/i18next/i18next-http-middleware/blob/master/example/basic-pug/views/index.pug#L5

Comment: please provide a real minimum example... just 1 simple route, not your complete app... seems for 1 page view a lot of requests are done... without knowing exactly your complete app, this will be crazy to investigate...
please isolate your problem first!

Comment: The problem with the minimum example is that the UI depends on a docker container to get the forms

Comment: The translations are being done here https://github.com/openfoodfacts/kratos-selfservice-ui-node/blob/i18n/views/partials/ui_node_input_default.hbs#L5 using the __ it is from this module https://github.com/Aller-Couleur/handlebars-i18n