# Using i18next middleware, i18next.language is not returning the actual translation language

Tags: i18next

Node + EJS app, using `i18next-fs-backend` and `i18next-http-middleware`.

```js
[...]
const i18next = require('i18next'),
      i18next_backend = require('i18next-fs-backend'),
      i18next_middleware = require('i18next-http-middleware');

i18next
    .use(i18next_backend)
    .use(i18next_middleware.LanguageDetector)
    .init({
        preload: ['en', 'fr'],
        fallbackLng: 'en',
        backend: {
            loadPath: path.join(__dirname, '/locales/{{ns}}-{{lng}}.json')
        }, debug: true
    });

app.use(i18next_middleware.handle(i18next));

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    console.log(req.headers['accept-language'], ':', req.language, i18next.language, i18next.resolvedLanguage, i18next.languages);
    next();
});
```

With *accept-language* to `[en]`, it logs `en : en en en ['en']` and displays English.
With *accept-language* to `[fr]`, it logs `fr : fr en en ['en']`, but do displays French strings.

Why isn't `i18next.language` reflecting the actual translation language?
(Shouldn't the log be something like `fr : fr fr fr ['en', 'fr']`?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the middleware is creating a clone of `i18next` instance, passed in the request as `req.i18n` (as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74045097/1113376) ).

→ The language actually used for a specific request is in `req.i18n.resolvedLanguage`.

Spent several hours trying to figure this out so I'll leave it here.